# How to open a big file in Notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++

I tried opening a file of 800MB size in Notepad++. But i don't why Notepad++ showed only *269117242 chars 271450112 bytes* . Neither it showed any alert message that it is unable to open such a big file. Then i used wordpad to open the same file, it worked like charm.

But why Notepad++ can't open 800MB file? I assume there must be some setting which says show only this much text.

*P.S. Please don't suggest any other software which can open big files. I know they exist.*

Comment: It is in general not a good idea to say something such as what you have mentioned in the postscriptum. "P.S. Please don't suggest any other software which can open big files. I know they exist."

Comment: @bubu I added this text because otherwise you would see lots of answer which will say use this `xyz` software to open huge files. But this was not my question. I simply wanted to know `why` Notepad++ can't open.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Notepad++ doesn't support huge files, according to [this](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Large_Text_Files) wiki documentation, the problem persists if the component (Scintilla) remains as the core of Notepad++ :

> Older versions of Notepad++ may crash
> while opening very large files. Newer
> versions (5.2+) will deny opening the
> file and issue an error message. Why
> is that?
>
> Notepad++ is based on a component
> (Scintilla) which is geared towards
> providing rich text viewing, with
> syntax highlighting and code folding,
> as opposed to bulk text services.
> There are necessary trade offs.
> Loading a 200MB file will require
> around 800MB of memory, and the OS may
> balk at the memory allocation request.
>
> There are basically two ways out:
>
> - Split the huge file into manageable chunks, and keep only one of them in editor;
> - Use another tool which is tailored to handle massive text files.
>
> If you still manage to open a large
> file, performance may not be optimal.
> Here is a couple things to think
> about:
>
> - Plugins which analyse and scan text will slow down NP++, disable them if possible
> - Parsing for clickable links on loading the document is slow if the document is large; disabling the clickable links has been reported to significantly help.

Another page on sourceforge also suggests that this problem persists throughout Notepad++'s life, as [the community requested to solve this problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20140418033733/http://sourceforge.net:80/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/24/):

Why don't you try other software such as [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php)? Is there any reason?

Comment: 64 bit gvim at http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/

Comment: If Wordpad can open the file, which also allows for rich text editing, I'd say this is a bug in Scintilla. Also gVim appears to be a windowed shim around a console based editor. I would not consider it comparable to NotePad++, which is a fully functional, natively windowed editor.

Comment: I would look into EditPad Lite. Tho even that only supports up to 2GB files. The Pro version supports larger ones. Very good. Instantly opens the big files.

Comment: @lamwaiman1988, Does the Notepad++ minimalist veresion helps?

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 : the gvim official ᴡindows® installer is 32 bits and doesn’t handle large files.

Comment: 64bit gVim available here https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases
scroll down there is a link to 64 bit installer

Comment: `Loading a 200MB file will require around 800MB of memory, and the OS may balk at the memory allocation request.` What century is this? My laptop has 40 GB of RAM. At least they could print the max size, so people would know.

Comment: Also note that in 2018 [a (experimental) patch was committed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scintilla-interest/TcqVCzi-tME/udkcc84pBwAJ;context-place=forum/scintilla-interest) to Scintilla that, I quote: The option to support documents larger than 2GB has been committed.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax highlighting is one of the main sources of slow performance in Notepad++.

If you're about to open a massive HTML, PHP, etc file in Notepad++, then you should first disable the syntax highlighting for that file by going to **Language** > **N** > **Normal Text**.

[image]

You should also disable clickable links. To do that, navigate to **Settings** > **Preferences** > **MISC.** > **Clickable Link Settings** and **uncheck the Enable checkbox**.

[image]